# IntelliJ JavaDoc inspector for HTML5 tags possible?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I am using the IntelliJ inspector to detect HTML issues in JavaDoc in when writing java docs. Per Java 11 the [default output of JavaDoc is HTML5](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javadoc.html).  However, I am struggling with inspector from IntelliJ with some false alarms because it still validates for HTML4 tags.

For example, I want to add a border to the JavaDoc table (`<table border="1">`), which claims be valid in IntelliJ, but is not valid for HTML5.

My question: *Is there an option to tell IntelliJ inspector to validate for HTML5 JavaDoc tags (instead of HTML4)?* . I am using IntelliJ 2019.2.3.

Thank you, Christoph

[image]

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Reported as: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229388